# Why is my static_for implementation in C++ slower than regular 'for' loop

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I implemented a `static_for` class to take advantage of compiler efficiency, but the results in terms of efficiency is not at all what I expected.

The class is as follows:

```
namespace std{
template <int First, int Last>
class static_for
{
public:
    template <typename Lambda>
    static inline constexpr void apply(Lambda const& f)
    {
        if (First < Last)
        {
            f(std::integral_constant<int, First>{});
            static_for<First + 1, Last>::apply(f);
        }
    }
};
template <int N>
class static_for<N, N>
{
public:
    template <typename Lambda>
    static inline constexpr void apply(Lambda const& f) { f(std::integral_constant<int, N>{}); }
};
}
```

To test if this is actually more efficient, I calculate the avg and sd (actually variance, but this is not the point of the post) of a randomly generated vector of doubles:

```
std::vector<double> t;
std::vector<double> t1;
std::vector<double> t2;

std::srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    int b = std::rand() % 20 + 1;
    t.push_back(b);
}

//Static-for
for (int i = 0; i < 9000000; ++i)
{
    double N = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    double sd = 0;
    std::static_for<0, 1000>::apply([&](auto j)
    {
        avg += t[i + j.value];
        sd += t[i + j.value] * t[i + j.value];
        ++N;
    });
    avg /= N;
    sd /= N;
    sd -= avg * avg;
    t1.push_back(sd);
}

//Dynamic-for
for (int i = 0; i < 9000000; ++i)
{
    double N = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    double sd = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= 1000; ++j)
    {
        avg += t[i + j];
        sd += t[i + j] * t[i + j];
        ++N;
    }
    avg /= N;
    sd /= N;
    sd -= avg * avg;
    t2.push_back(sd);
}
```

Note: you can change the 1000 to a lower number if it is creating a template depth problem because, again, it is not the point here.

I would expect the first piece to execute faster than the second piece, but it does not. I think the the compiler is forcing a dynamic call to each separate `static_for<X,Y>::apply` instead of putting the code inline.

I am using Visual C++ 2017. So

1. how do I confirm my hypothesis, that the code is not being inlined;
2. how do I fix this?

**Adding ASM code:**

So looking at the ASM (which is ~147k lines) I find the following:

; Line 19
    jmp ??$apply@V@@@?$static_for@$00$0DOI@@std@@SAXAEBV@@@Z ; std::static_for<1,1000>::apply< >
??$apply@V@@@?$static_for@$0A@$0DOI@@std@@SAXAEBV@@@Z ENDP ; std::static_for<0,1000>::apply< >
_TEXT   ENDS

And the next time I see this it looks like this:

; Line 19
    mov rcx, r11
    jmp ??$apply@V@@@?$static_for@$0L@$0DOI@@std@@SAXAEBV@@@Z ; std::static_for<11,1000>::apply< >
??$apply@V@@@?$static_for@$00$0DOI@@std@@SAXAEBV@@@Z ENDP ; std::static_for<1,1000>::apply< >
_TEXT   ENDS

Note that it moves on to `static_for<11,1000>`, and it unrolls 1 through 10.
And then 21, starting from 11 to 20. And so on until the end.
Also, in the beginning there was a lonesome `static_for<0,1000>`.

Not sure if this is sufficient start point to see what is going on. Let me know what else you may need.

Comment: Agressive loop optimization? What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: Possible answer: The cost of calling a function 1000 times is more than that to increment a variable 1000 times. Calling function has its overhead.

Comment: Perusing the generated ASM on your platform would probably tell you quite a lot. in particular whether your suspicions about inline failure are founded. So, did you generate the release-mode asm with optimizations cranked, and if so, what did it show?

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. Post your compiler flags. Check the generated assembly. Can't really give you an answer without more info.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < some_constant; ++i)` is an extremely common pattern. Don't expect to be smarter than an optimizing compiler.

Comment: Hint: when doing measurements, use a fixed random seed, to get reproducible results.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I generated an ASM, but it is my first time playing around with this. So bare with me, I am posting additional comments above.

Comment: I don't think it's clear-cut that unrolling this loop into ~11k instructions (which is what happens [using GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/FYJ2XA) at least) is going to be faster than the ~10 instruction loop a plain for-loop gives you.

Comment: Also, don't add stuff to the `std` namespace; [it is undefined behavior to do so](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).

Comment: The main overhead of loops is the branch miss-prediction at the end. For long-running loops this can be negligible. My guess is that your loop-unrolling could beat the for loop for short loops.

Comment: So when the top constant is 8 or less, then the loop is comparable to the for loop.  For 9 or greater, the loop suddenly drops greatly in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this:

```
template <typename Lambda>
static inline constexpr void apply(Lambda&& f)
```

I've found passing by reference for this kind of meta programming can sometimes cause the compiler to do the wrong thing.

And for good measure you could also `FORCE_INLINE`:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define FORCE_INLINE __forceinline
#else
#define FORCE_INLINE __attribute__((always_inline))
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks keith. I tried this, and also I had the force inline added, but it doesn't seem to make an overall difference. I will add this into my addition to the main question post.

Comment: So I revisited your solution, and it seems that using the macro you provided does not actually FORCE_INLINE, but if I replace `inline` with `__forceinline` then it works, but in so much as it only raises the number of loops I can push through the `static_for` before it stops being efficient. I think that at some depth level, the compiler simply doesn't bother anymore.

Comment: Were your replacing `inline` with `FORCE_INLINE` or adding `FORCE_INLINE` as well? You can control the level of template recursion in MSVC, although I think there is a solution to writing a TMP based for loop by sinking a variadic template expansion via a `std::integer_sequence` which has no recursion to expand the for loop.

Comment: Interesting, I will give that a try.  Although, given where there is a solution a new problem is found, I suspect that std::integer_sequence will also have its own limitations with how many integers can be strung together.

Answer (score 1):

First: You can use Google Benchmark. I downloaded and and compiled it into a lib (MSVC), now I can add it to my benchamrking Projects. It is available online (quick-bench.com), but it doesn't allow to run long benchmarks.

To compare Assembly code, compiler explorer is the tool to use. (godbolt.org)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question too well. I think it should be a comment.

Comment: The question is: "1) how do I confirm my hypothesis, that the code is not being inlined;"